# CMUSphix does not recognize

Tags: c++, voice-recognition, cmusphinx

I try to test CMUSphinx library work under Windows.
I check tutorial in the http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx
and build the sphinxbase and pokectsphinx library.

Then I try to check builded library for working and start pocketsphinx_continuous.exe app with next options:

```
C:\Users\admin>D:\Work\Elis\Win32\pocketsphinx-0.8-win32\bin\Release\pocketsphinx_continuous.exe -hmm d:\Work\Elis\Win32\pocketsphinx-0.8-win32\model\hm
    m\en_US\hub4wsj_sc_8k -dic d:\Work\Elis\Win32\pocketsphinx-0.8-win32\model\lm\en
    _US\cmu07a.dic -lm d:\Work\Elis\Win32\pocketsphinx-0.8-win32\model\lm\en_US\wsj0
    vp.5000.DMP
```

After that in console I see next:

```
INFO: cmd_ln.c(691): Parsing command line:
    D:\Work\Elis\Win32\pocketsphinx-0.8-win32\bin\Release\pocketsphinx_continuous.ex
    e \
            -hmm d:\Work\Elis\Win32\pocketsphinx-0.8-win32\model\hmm\en_US\hub4wsj_s
    c_8k \
            -dic d:\Work\Elis\Win32\pocketsphinx-0.8-win32\model\lm\en_US\cmu07a.dic
     \
            -lm d:\Work\Elis\Win32\pocketsphinx-0.8-win32\model\lm\en_US\wsj0vp.5000
    .DMP

    Current configuration:
    [NAME]          [DEFLT]         [VALUE]
    -adcdev
    -agc            none            none
    -agcthresh      2.0             2.000000e+000
    -alpha          0.97            9.700000e-001
    -argfile
    -ascale         20.0            2.000000e+001
    -aw             1               1
    -backtrace      no              no
    -beam           1e-48           1.000000e-048
    -bestpath       yes             yes
    -bestpathlw     9.5             9.500000e+000
    -bghist         no              no
    -ceplen         13              13
    -cmn            current         current
    -cmninit        8.0             8.0
    -compallsen     no              no
    -debug                          0
    -dict
    -dictcase       no              no
    -dither         no              no
    -doublebw       no              no
    -ds             1               1
    -fdict
    -feat           1s_c_d_dd       1s_c_d_dd
    -featparams
    -fillprob       1e-8            1.000000e-008
    -frate          100             100
    -fsg
    -fsgusealtpron  yes             yes
    -fsgusefiller   yes             yes
    -fwdflat        yes             yes
    -fwdflatbeam    1e-64           1.000000e-064
    -fwdflatefwid   4               4
    -fwdflatlw      8.5             8.500000e+000
    -fwdflatsfwin   25              25
    -fwdflatwbeam   7e-29           7.000000e-029
    -fwdtree        yes             yes
    -hmm                            d:\Work\Elis\Win32\pocketsphinx-0.8-win32\model\
    hmm\en_US\hub4wsj_sc_8k
    -infile
    -input_endian   little          little
    -jsgf
    -kdmaxbbi       -1              -1
    -kdmaxdepth     0               0
    -kdtree
    -latsize        5000            5000
    -lda
    -ldadim         0               0
    -lextreedump    0               0
    -lifter         0               0
    -lm                             d:\Work\Elis\Win32\pocketsphinx-0.8-win32\model\
    lm\en_US\wsj0vp.5000.DMP
    -lmctl
    -lmname         default         default
    -logbase        1.0001          1.000100e+000
    -logfn
    -logspec        no              no
    -lowerf         133.33334       1.333333e+002
    -lpbeam         1e-40           1.000000e-040
    -lponlybeam     7e-29           7.000000e-029
    -lw             6.5             6.500000e+000
    -maxhmmpf       -1              -1
    -maxnewoov      20              20
    -maxwpf         -1              -1
    -mdef
    -mean
    -mfclogdir
    -min_endfr      0               0
    -mixw
    -mixwfloor      0.0000001       1.000000e-007
    -mllr
    -mmap           yes             yes
    -ncep           13              13
    -nfft           512             512
    -nfilt          40              40
    -nwpen          1.0             1.000000e+000
    -pbeam          1e-48           1.000000e-048
    -pip            1.0             1.000000e+000
    -pl_beam        1e-10           1.000000e-010
    -pl_pbeam       1e-5            1.000000e-005
    -pl_window      0               0
    -rawlogdir
    -remove_dc      no              no
    -round_filters  yes             yes
    -samprate       16000           1.600000e+004
    -seed           -1              -1
    -sendump
    -senlogdir
    -senmgau
    -silprob        0.005           5.000000e-003
    -smoothspec     no              no
    -svspec
    -time           no              no
    -tmat
    -tmatfloor      0.0001          1.000000e-004
    -topn           4               4
    -topn_beam      0               0
    -toprule
    -transform      legacy          legacy
    -unit_area      yes             yes
    -upperf         6855.4976       6.855498e+003
    -usewdphones    no              no
    -uw             1.0             1.000000e+000
    -var
    -varfloor       0.0001          1.000000e-004
    -varnorm        no              no
    -verbose        no              no
    -warp_params
    -warp_type      inverse_linear  inverse_linear
    -wbeam          7e-29           7.000000e-029
    -wip            0.65            6.500000e-001
    -wlen           0.025625        2.562500e-002

    INFO: cmd_ln.c(691): Parsing command line:
    \
            -nfilt 20 \
            -lowerf 1 \
            -upperf 4000 \
            -wlen 0.025 \
            -transform dct \
            -round_filters no \
            -remove_dc yes \
            -svspec 0-12/13-25/26-38 \
            -feat 1s_c_d_dd \
            -agc none \
            -cmn current \
            -cmninit 56,-3,1 \
            -varnorm no

    Current configuration:
    [NAME]          [DEFLT]         [VALUE]
    -agc            none            none
    -agcthresh      2.0             2.000000e+000
    -alpha          0.97            9.700000e-001
    -ceplen         13              13
    -cmn            current         current
    -cmninit        8.0             56,-3,1
    -dither         no              no
    -doublebw       no              no
    -feat           1s_c_d_dd       1s_c_d_dd
    -frate          100             100
    -input_endian   little          little
    -lda
    -ldadim         0               0
    -lifter         0               0
    -logspec        no              no
    -lowerf         133.33334       1.000000e+000
    -ncep           13              13
    -nfft           512             512
    -nfilt          40              20
    -remove_dc      no              yes
    -round_filters  yes             no
    -samprate       16000           1.600000e+004
    -seed           -1              -1
    -smoothspec     no              no
    -svspec                         0-12/13-25/26-38
    -transform      legacy          dct
    -unit_area      yes             yes
    -upperf         6855.4976       4.000000e+003
    -varnorm        no              no
    -verbose        no              no
    -warp_params
    -warp_type      inverse_linear  inverse_linear
    -wlen           0.025625        2.500000e-002

    INFO: acmod.c(246): Parsed model-specific feature parameters from d:\Work\Elis\W
    in32\pocketsphinx-0.8-win32\model\hmm\en_US\hub4wsj_sc_8k/feat.params
    INFO: feat.c(713): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13,
    CMN='current', VARNORM='no', AGC='none'
    INFO: cmn.c(142): mean[0]= 12.00, mean[1..12]= 0.0
    INFO: acmod.c(167): Using subvector specification 0-12/13-25/26-38
    INFO: mdef.c(517): Reading model definition: d:\Work\Elis\Win32\pocketsphinx-0.8
    -win32\model\hmm\en_US\hub4wsj_sc_8k/mdef
    INFO: mdef.c(528): Found byte-order mark BMDF, assuming this is a binary mdef fi
    le
    INFO: bin_mdef.c(336): Reading binary model definition: d:\Work\Elis\Win32\pocke
    tsphinx-0.8-win32\model\hmm\en_US\hub4wsj_sc_8k/mdef
    INFO: bin_mdef.c(513): 50 CI-phone, 143047 CD-phone, 3 emitstate/phone, 150 CI-s
    en, 5150 Sen, 27135 Sen-Seq
    INFO: tmat.c(205): Reading HMM transition probability matrices: d:\Work\Elis\Win
    32\pocketsphinx-0.8-win32\model\hmm\en_US\hub4wsj_sc_8k/transition_matrices
    INFO: acmod.c(121): Attempting to use SCHMM computation module
    INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: d:\Work\Elis\Win32\p
    ocketsphinx-0.8-win32\model\hmm\en_US\hub4wsj_sc_8k/means
    INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 1 codebook, 3 feature, size:
    INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
    INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
    INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
    INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: d:\Work\Elis\Win32\p
    ocketsphinx-0.8-win32\model\hmm\en_US\hub4wsj_sc_8k/variances
    INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 1 codebook, 3 feature, size:
    INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
    INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
    INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
    INFO: ms_gauden.c(354): 0 variance values floored
    INFO: s2_semi_mgau.c(903): Loading senones from dump file d:\Work\Elis\Win32\poc
    ketsphinx-0.8-win32\model\hmm\en_US\hub4wsj_sc_8k/sendump
    INFO: s2_semi_mgau.c(927): BEGIN FILE FORMAT DESCRIPTION
    INFO: s2_semi_mgau.c(1022): Using memory-mapped I/O for senones
    INFO: s2_semi_mgau.c(1296): Maximum top-N: 4 Top-N beams: 0 0 0
    INFO: dict.c(317): Allocating 4107 * 20 bytes (80 KiB) for word entries
    INFO: dict.c(341): Reading filler dictionary: d:\Work\Elis\Win32\pocketsphinx-0.
    8-win32\model\hmm\en_US\hub4wsj_sc_8k/noisedict
    INFO: dict.c(211): Allocated 0 KiB for strings, 0 KiB for phones
    INFO: dict.c(344): 11 words read
    INFO: dict2pid.c(396): Building PID tables for dictionary
    INFO: dict2pid.c(404): Allocating 50^3 * 2 bytes (244 KiB) for word-initial trip
    hones
    INFO: dict2pid.c(131): Allocated 30200 bytes (29 KiB) for word-final triphones
    INFO: dict2pid.c(195): Allocated 30200 bytes (29 KiB) for single-phone word trip
    hones
    INFO: ngram_model_arpa.c(77): No \data\ mark in LM file
    INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(142): Will use memory-mapped I/O for LM file
    INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(196): ngrams 1=5002, 2=338656, 3=291318
    INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(242):     5002 = LM.unigrams(+trailer) read
    INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(288):   338656 = LM.bigrams(+trailer) read
    INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(314):   291318 = LM.trigrams read
    INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(339):    32470 = LM.prob2 entries read
    INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(359):    13795 = LM.bo_wt2 entries read
    INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(379):    31136 = LM.prob3 entries read
    INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(407):      662 = LM.tseg_base entries read
    INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(463):     5002 = ascii word strings read
    INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(99): 0 unique initial diphones
    INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(147): 0 root, 0 non-root channels, 12 single-phone
    words
    INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(186): Creating search tree
    INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(191): before: 0 root, 0 non-root channels, 12 singl
    e-phone words
    INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(326): after: max nonroot chan increased to 128
    ERROR: "ngram_search_fwdtree.c", line 336: No word from the language model has p
    ronunciation in the dictionary
    INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(338): after: 0 root, 0 non-root channels, 11 single
    -phone words
    INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(156): fwdflat: min_ef_width = 4, max_sf_win = 25
    INFO: continuous.c(371): D:\Work\Elis\Win32\pocketsphinx-0.8-win32\bin\Release\p
    ocketsphinx_continuous.exe COMPILED ON: Dec 13 2012, AT: 17:37:32

    Allocating 32 buffers of 2500 samples each
    READY....
```

Then I say some text and pocketsphinx_continuous try to recognize is, but I see empty output

```
Listening...
Stopped listening, please wait...
INFO: cmn_prior.c(121): cmn_prior_update: from < 56.00 -3.00  1.00  0.00  0.00
0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 >
INFO: cmn_prior.c(139): cmn_prior_update: to   < 44.82 -2.76 -3.93 -1.62 -0.65 -
0.61  1.56  0.45 -0.66 -0.44  0.32 -0.32  0.06 >
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1549):      593 words recognized (8/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1551):     1818 senones evaluated (25/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1553):      720 channels searched (10/fr), 0 1st, 7
20 last
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1557):      720 words for which last channels evalu
ated (10/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1560):        0 candidate words for entering last p
hone (0/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1562): fwdtree 0.00 CPU 0.000 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1565): fwdtree 1.59 wall 2.208 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(302): Utterance vocabulary contains 2 words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(937):       77 words recognized (1/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(939):      213 senones evaluated (3/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(941):      145 channels searched (2/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(943):      145 words searched (2/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(945):       58 word transitions (0/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(948): fwdflat 0.02 CPU 0.022 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(951): fwdflat 0.00 wall 0.007 xRT
INFO: ngram_search.c(1214): </s> not found in last frame, using <sil>.70 instead

INFO: ngram_search.c(1266): lattice start node <s>.0 end node <sil>.55
INFO: ngram_search.c(1294): Eliminated 0 nodes before end node
INFO: ngram_search.c(1399): Lattice has 3 nodes, 2 links
INFO: ps_lattice.c(1365): Normalizer P(O) = alpha(<sil>:55:70) = -602868
INFO: ps_lattice.c(1403): Joint P(O,S) = -602868 P(S|O) = 0
INFO: ngram_search.c(888): bestpath 0.02 CPU 0.022 xRT
INFO: ngram_search.c(891): bestpath 0.00 wall 0.006 xRT
000000000:
READY....
```

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Add **-rawlogdir <dir-name>** to store the raw log data passed to recognizer. Run recognizer again. Share raw files created.

Comment: Hello Nikolay,
Thnak you for your reply. I added this option to recognizer. You can download it from next link

[link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47335453/work/Elis/RawData.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ERROR: "ngram_search_fwdtree.c", line 336: No word from the language model has p
>       ronunciation in the dictionary

This error from the log should hint you something went wrong.

Actually, you are using the wrong option, you should use `-dict cmudict.dic`, not `-dic cmudict.dic`

Comment: Thank you, everything works... almost everything... unfotenately my accuracy is poor...